# Reply to functionality in mscrm 2011 Email Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Outlook allows you to set the default reply-to address to something other than your own email,
  but you can also use more than one email address into that field, which will tell the recipient’s mail client to reply to a list of email addresses,
  not just yours. Is it possible to achieve reply to functionality in  mscrm 2011, out of box functionality is present? I want to achieve functionality to the link given below in mscrm2011.  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/send-email-replies-to-another-recipient-in-outlook-2007/.  Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRM cannot meet this requirement as it is currently designed. If you look at the Email Provider documentation (it is only available in the CRM 4 SDK, not the 2011 SDK) there is no property for a reply-to address. (Here is the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc905922)

It might be possible if you coded a custom e-mail provider but you would be taking on a good bit of work if you went down that path.

I would suggest looking into if this can be on the Exchange server (or whatever e-mail system you are using.) I'm by no means an Exchange expert so I don't know what is possible on the Exchange platform, but I do know that CRM does support setting the reply-to address.